# Detect pixels in an object that are off-screen in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework, stage3d

Is there a way (using Starling, Stage3d, or any other Flash framework) to determine if certain pixels are actually being rendered (vs. off screen due to browser scrolling or covered by another window)?

I know there are events to let an app know if the entire player has been throttled due to it getting moved off screen, but if even one pixel in the app is visible the entire player is un-throttled.

Is there any property or performance metric that can tell my app it's ok to stop wasting cycles on an object that isn't being drawn to the screen when another part of the stage is?

(Sorry this is so vague.)

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: IIRC Flash rendering is all or nothing, that is, you MIGHT get info about your app not rendering, but you will not be able to get info of which part of Flash window is visible, an which is not.

Comment: I think this is the job of Flash Player developers to optimize their technology or to give us the hand to do it, no ?